# Plotting coefficients in a quantile regression in R

Tags: r, quantile, quantile-regression

I am having a problem plotting coefficients for a quantile regression in R Studio. Here is my code:
`plot(summary(rq(data = d, normalized_losses ~ price +  highway_mpg + fuel_type, tau = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9))))`

Unfortunately, it doesn't plot (only) fuel_type, which is a factor variable in 2 levels. It gets this error:

> Error in plot.window(...) : infinite axis extents [GEPretty(-inf,inf,5)]

I tried to add **ylim=c(-Inf,Inf)**, getting something like:

```
plot(summary(rq(data = d,
            normalized_losses ~ price +  highway_mpg + fuel_type,
            tau = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9))), ylim=c(-Inf,Inf))
```

It seems it works, but I cannot see the coefficients in the plot because *price* is too small or *highway_mpg* is too large.

Here the data:

```
 symboling normalized_losses make fuel_type aspiration num_of_doors body_style
1         2               164 audi         2        std         four      sedan
2         2               164 audi         2        std         four      sedan
3         1               158 audi         2        std         four      sedan
4         1               158 audi         2      turbo         four      sedan
5         2               192  bmw         2        std          two      sedan
6         0               192  bmw         2        std         four      sedan
  drive_wheels engine_location wheel_base length width height curb_weight engine_type
1          fwd           front      99.80 176.60 66.20  54.30        2337         ohc
2          4wd           front      99.40 176.60 66.40  54.30        2824         ohc
3          fwd           front     105.80 192.70 71.40  55.70        2844             ohc
4          fwd           front     105.80 192.70 71.40  55.90        3086         ohc
5          rwd           front     101.20 176.80 64.80  54.30        2395             ohc
6          rwd           front     101.20 176.80 64.80  54.30        2395         ohc
  num_of_cylinders engine_size fuel_system bore stroke compression_ratio horsepower
1             four         109        mpfi 3.19   3.40             10.00        102
2             five         136        mpfi 3.19   3.40              8.00        115
3             five         136        mpfi 3.19   3.40              8.50        110
4             five         131        mpfi 3.13   3.40              8.30        140
5             four         108        mpfi 3.50   2.80              8.80        101
6             four         108        mpfi 3.50   2.80              8.80        101
  peak_rpm city_mpg highway_mpg price
1     5500       24          30 13950
2     5500       18          22 17450
3     5500       19          25 17710
4     5500       17          20 23875
5     5800       23          29 16430
6     5800       23          29 16925
```

It gets only the first three coefficients, no the fuel_type!
[image: Plot coefficients]

Comment: It would really help if you provided your data in a way that it easier for us to copy and use directly, such as `dput(d)` (or `dput(head(d))` if large).

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are using the `quantreg` package?

Comment: Yes, I am using the **quantreg** package